# memory buffer routines:BUF_MEM_grow_clean:malloc while decrypt files bigger than 1.5 GB

Tags: encryption, openssl

I have a basic script that backups, compress and encrypts a MySQL dump:

```
mysqldump --events --routines --triggers --add-drop-database \
  --compress --hex-blob --opt --skip-comments --single-transaction \
  my-database | \
  xz -c | \
  /usr/bin/openssl smime \
  -encrypt \
  -aes256 \
  -binary \
  -out /mnt/test.sql.xz.enc \
  -outform DER /path/to/cert.pem
```

To encrypt basically this command is used:

```
openssl smime -encrypt -aes256 -binary -out test.sql.xz.enc -outform DER cert.pem
```

To decrypt normally I use:

```
openssl smime -decrypt -in test.sql.xz.enc -binary -inform DEM -inkey private.key -out sql.xz
```

Over the time this has been working in both ways, encrypting and decrypting but now that the data after being compressed has reached more than **1.5GB** while decrypting I am getting this error:

```
Error reading S/MIME message      
34380825992:error:07069041:memory buffer 
routines:BUF_MEM_grow_clean:malloc failure:/usr/src/secure/lib/libcrypto/../../../crypto/openssl/crypto/buffer/buffer.c:150:
34380825992:error:0D06B041:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_READ_BIO:malloc failure:/usr/src/secure/lib/libcrypto/../../../crypto/openssl/crypto/asn1/a_d2i_fp.c:239:
```

I have move the file to a biger instance (4 cores, 8GB ram) but still have the issue.

Therefore wondering if there is a size limit while encrypting using the `smime` option, and what options could be used to encrypt/decrypt files in the order of gigabytes.

For now, I am testing with the option `-stream` seems to be working:

```
openssl smime -encrypt -aes256 -stream -binary -out test.sql.xz.enc -outform DER cert.pem
```

but don't know what will be the limit, so any possible alternatives or ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: When you are using -stream then you probably won't hit this memory problem. The whole point of -stream option is that it will divide large files into smaller chunks (let's say 4096 bytes per chunk) and encrypt/decrypt these small chunks in many iterations.